# how to insert update delete operations on wpf mvvm using list?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Here i have written the update operation, and also i would like to know how to perform insert and delete opearations on MVVM?

```
View section:
```

filename: Person.xaml----> it is UI designing file

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.View.Person"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Person" Height="300" Width="300" 
        xmlns:y="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5.ViewModel">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding ElementName=lstPerson, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"></TextBox>
            <Label x:Name="lblAddress" Content="Address" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding ElementName=lstPerson, Path=SelectedItem.Address}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Width="100" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Content="Update"
                Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstPerson, Path=SelectedItem.Address}"></Button>
        <ListView x:Name="lstPerson" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Address" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>


VieModel section:
```

Filename is: PersonViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using WpfApplication5.Model;

namespace WpfApplication5.ViewModel
{
    class PersonViewModel
    {
        private IList<Person> _personList;
        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            _personList = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person(){Name="Prabhat", Address="Bangalore"},
                new Person(){Name="John",Address="Delhi"}
            };
        }
        public IList<Person> Persons
        {
            get { return _personList; }
            set { _personList = value; }
        }
        private ICommand mUpdater;
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (mUpdater == null)
                    mUpdater = new Updater();
                return mUpdater;
            }
            set
            {
                mUpdater = value;
            }
        }
    }
    class Updater : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //Your Code
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

Model section:
```

filename is:Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication5.Model
{
    class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return address;
            }
            set
            {
                address = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply add/delete to the collection your listView is binded to.

Comment: @RohitVats: Thank you for your response and please provide me the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **`List<T>`**, use [**ObservableCollection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) for source collection.

Reason being it implements **`INotifyCollectionChanged`** which means any insert/add/delete operation to this list will refresh bounded UI automatically. You need not to worry about raising collection changed events.

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _personList;
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
   get { return _personList; }
   set { _personList = value; }
}
```

---

Moreover, instead of creating separate class for each implementation of ICommand, consider using generic version of **`RelayCommand`** or **`DelegateCommand`**.

**RelayCommand**:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Use RelayCommand and create handlers within your ViewModel class like this:

```
private ICommand mUpdater;
public ICommand UpdateCommand
{
    get
    {
       if (mUpdater == null)
          mUpdater = new RelayCommand<object>(Update);
       return mUpdater;
    }
}

private void Update(object parameter)
{
    // Update collection based on the parameter passed from View.
}
```

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for your response. I am getting little bit confusion.so can you please give me the full code of insert, update, delete operation in WPF using mvvm architecture.

Comment: What's the confusion? Moreover I have provided the code to get you started. Try this out and post problems you faced here.

Comment: (or) edit my code to perform insert, update, delete operations. thank you in advance

Comment: You have only single button to perform update operation wherein you are passing address of selected item. I am assuming you want to update the address of that person to some value. In parameter you will get the value, just update it to the desired value. I'll update it for update operation. Same you can do for add/delete.

Comment: same way we need to add the buttons for insert and delete?

Comment: Right for add/delete create two more commands in ViewModel and bind button to that command. For delete in command parameter pass SelectedItem of ListView like you are passing in update command. And in handler simply delete that item - `Persons.Delete(parameter as Person);`.

Comment: For add in handler, just create new instance of person class and add that object in collection - `Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Test"});`.

Comment: ok. please give me the full code like view, viewmodel, model sections

Comment: Ah. Seems you are new to the site. This site is for providing solutions to the problems which you faces while carrying out the problem. Not for providing ready made solutions. I have already posted the solution which will get you going. Try out yourself and in case face some issue post the problem here. No one here will entertain homework questions (if you asks one, your question is deemed to be closed sooner or later). Happy coding :)